# How to Format Date in Mule Data weave

Tags: dataweave, mule4

How i can format the Date in Dataweave. I tried with the options mentioned in the MuleSoft Documentation. My Date in payload coming as

```
"noteDate": "2018-12-01 00:00:00",
```

My Function in Dataweave is

```
fun getFormattedDate(data) =
if ( data !=null ) data as  String {format: "uuuu-MM-dd"}
else
null
```

But its not formatting at all . Expected output is "2018-12-01"

Comment: Could you please update your question to include the expected output? Thank you!

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload.noteDate as LocalDateTime {"format": "uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"} as String {"format": "uuuu-MM-dd"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this function which will work for both null and dateTime values.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
fun GenericDate(dateTime) = (dateTime as LocalDateTime {format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"} as Date) default null
---
GenericDate(payload.noteDate)
```